# Is the logging mechanism from Spring4D thread-safe? (units Spring.Logging.*, I suppose)

Tags: multithreading, delphi, logging, spring4d

Is the logging mechanism from Spring4D thread-safe? (units Spring.Logging.*, I suppose)

For example, can several threads resolve and use an implementation for `ILogger` from the following container?

```
uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Spring.Container,
  Spring.Logging,
  Spring.Logging.Appenders,
  Spring.Logging.Controller,
  Spring.Logging.Loggers;

var
  Container: TContainer;
  TextLogAppender: TTextLogAppender;
  FileLogAppender: TFileLogAppender;
  LoggerController: TLoggerController;
  LoggerInThread1: ILogger;
  LoggerInThread2: ILogger;
begin
  TextLogAppender := TTextLogAppender.Create;
  FileLogAppender := TFileLogAppender.Create;
  FileLogAppender.FileName := 'Log.txt';
  LoggerController := TLoggerController.Create;
  LoggerController.AddAppender(TextLogAppender as ILogAppender);
  LoggerController.AddAppender(FileLogAppender as ILogAppender);

  Container := TContainer.Create;
  try
    Container.RegisterInstance<ILoggerController>(LoggerController);
    Container.RegisterType<ILogger, TLogger>;

    Container.Build;

    LoggerInThread1 := Container.Resolve<ILogger>;
    LoggerInThread2 := Container.Resolve<ILogger>;

    {$Region 'threaded code'}
    LoggerInThread1.Info('Hello from Thread 1!');
    LoggerInThread2.Info('Hello from Thread 2!');
    {$EndRegion}
  finally
    Container.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Using branch [release/1.2](https://bitbucket.org/sglienke/spring4d/commits/branch/release/1.2) (currently [33e3232...](https://bitbucket.org/sglienke/spring4d/src/33e3232ba720005f6fce3b5e25bf7d10eea7bd3b?at=release/1.2)).

Answer (score 3):

`TFileLogAppender` can be used from multiple threads at the same time since it derives from `TStreamLogAppender` which uses a `TCriticalSection` in its `DoSend` method in order to avoid problems related to multithreading.

`TTextLogAppender` **does not** use an instance of `TCriticalSection` in its implementation of `DoSend`. So I don't think it's supposed to work in mutliple threads at the same time.

Comment: TTextLogAppender is not thread-safe since it uses file I/O (aka Writeln). Even putting a CS into that would not solve anything since there could be multiple appenders writing to the same file. Which is why TStreamLogAppender is also only thread-safe if you don't have another that uses the same stream.

Comment: To sum this up: `TFileLogAppender` is thread safe since it uses the CS from the `TStreamLogAppender` and there is no risk of exposing the stream for other use, also it uses `fmShareDenyWrite` access which prohibits others from writing to the same file. `TTextLogAppender` is thread-safe as long as you use it for stdout/stderr (may be platform dependent). The other platform specific appenders should be safe as well (also platform dependent).

Comment: I have to correct myself, after few tests `TTextLogAppender` is **not** thread safe due to internal RTL implementation. I'll add locking for 1.2 that will fix that if the logging is the only one using `ErrOutput`. I created an [issue](https://bitbucket.org/sglienke/spring4d/issues/235) for you to track.